# quill.js Cannot find module webpack.config.js

Tags: javascript, npm, quill

For the local development of quill, cloned the source from quill develop branch 
and followed the following steps,

1. npm install
2. gem install foreman jekyll kramdown rouge jekyll-sitemap
   jekyll-redirect-from jekyll-feed
3. npm run build

While running **npm run build** getting error as,
npm build failed in, webpack --config _develop/webpack.config.js; rm dist/quill.core dist/quill.bubble dist/quill.snow;

Error Cannot find module 'F:\quill_develop\webpack.config.js'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm following the [local development instructions](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/blob/master/.github/DEVELOPMENT.md) on Ubuntu 16.04 with Quill 1.0.6.

I'm not getting the above error.

Maybe it's npm specific issue on Windows?
What version of node.js and npm are you using?

```
sudo apt-get install git ruby ruby-dev
sudo gem install foreman jekyll kramdown rouge jekyll-sitemap jekyll-redirect-from jekyll-feed
git clone https://github.com/quilljs/quill
cd quill
npm install
npm run build
```

Comment: Am using Windows 7. Issue resolved, Thank you very much for your valuable response

Comment: @AshokJayaPrakash How did you solve this issue? I'm getting this as well now with quill 1.3.6 on windows.